# How do I get the return values from python-socketio to PYQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-socketio

How can I get the return value from socketio (python-socketio-version=4.5) in another Python script?

1. Tried a global variable.
2. Tried to call the Update function in another script.

->My goal is to pass the return value "data" to my GUI with pyqt5!

There may be a way to transfer or emit the data with PYQT5 like [PyQt5: How to connect() & emit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948455/pyqt5-how-to-connect-emit)

Additional information about socketio at: https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

> SocketIO.py

```
    import socketio
    sio = socketio.Client()
    @sio.on('connect', namespace='/packingUI')

    def on_connect(site='1000', resource='TC_DEPLOY_RES2_PACK'):
        sio.emit('register', {'site': site, 'resource': resource},namespace='/packingUI')
    
        @sio.on('update', namespace='/packingUI')
        def update(data):
            print(data)
            return data
        
        
        @sio.on('disconnect', namespace='/packingUI')
        def disconnect():
            print('disconnected from server')
        
        sio.connect('http://################################.com', namespaces=['/packingUI'])
        sio.wait()
```

> Test.py

```
import SocketIO
a=""
while True:
    b = SocketIO.update(a)
    print(b)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "in another script"? A different program? Use IPC. A different source file of the same program? Use regular parameters or (module-level) variables. This has nothing to do with where you get the variable from or what it is, those are Python basics. That said, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: In addition to what @UlrichEckhardt asked I would want a link to the `socketio` package. Is it https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/? Also, a socket connection involves operating resources; e.g., an open file-descriptor. You can't pass such an object to another process.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  Yes, it's my very first question here!  My goal is to display the answer from the SocketIo in pyqt!

Comment: A question title that briefly describes what the question is about would also be helpful. *Python socketio == 4.5* just doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to integrate python Socket.IO with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68383027/how-to-integrate-python-socket-io-with-qt)

Comment: That was the answer! Thank you so much....